# jammy-backports InRelease' changed its 'Suite' value from 'jammy-updates' to 'jammy-backports'

Tags: apt, 22.04

My `apt-get update` command fails with the following errors:

```
N: Repository 'http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease' changed its 'Suite' value from 'jammy-updates' to 'jammy-backports'
E: Repository 'http://at.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease' changed its default priority for apt_preferences(5) from 500 to 100.
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
```

I am worried about a security issue. Why am I seeing this error and what does it mean?